# How to set up periodic tasks automatically

Tags: django, celerybeat, django-celery-beat

I have a celery task in one of my django apps.

My `django`, `celery` and `django-celery-beat` services are ran in their own docker containers. Since this is a legacy project, I now assume they interact smoothly already with the current config.

What I want is that when the app gets deployed/started it finds my perioidc tasks automatically and registers them in the django celery beat database tables.

My task:

```py
# project.an_app.tasks.generate_statements
from config import celery_app

@celery_app.task(...)
def generate_statements():
    print("Statment generation runs. Current date and time:", datetime.now())
    # my task logic
```

This is one solution I've found. But this only gets triggered when I try to access the `Periodic tasks` tables via admin site (probably would be triggered other ways which interact with these tables, but I don't want to "wait" for anything like that).

```py
def schedule_task():
    interval, _ = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
        every=30,
        period=IntervalSchedule.SECONDS,
    )

    PeriodicTask.objects.get_or_create(
        interval=interval,
        name="generate-statements",
        task=project.an_app.tasks.generate_statements,
    )
    
schedule_task()
```

Looking at our legacy code I've found this, this one looks

```py
from project.an_app.tasks import generate_statements

@celery_app.on_after_finalize.connect
def register_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Callback for Celery to register periodic tasks.
    """
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        30.0,
        task=generate_statements,
        name="generate-statements",
    )
```

The task of the copied code is indeed already `django_celery_beat_periodictask` table. So I would say this works. However this version did not create my task when I rebuilt the docker containers.

Also I keep finding solutions of simply adding it in the `settings.py` file:

```py
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = "django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "task-name": {
        "task": "project.an_app.tasks.generate_statements",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
    },
}
```

This one did not work as well.

Can someone clear up which solution is the most suitable for what I want and what am I missing in each cases?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a Django app I have, there is first code in the project/_init.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)
```

Then I have a celery.py:

```
import os

from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "core.settings")

app = Celery("core")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

That should ensure that celery is loaded at project start and that the tasks is autodiscovered.

Don’t know if it helps in your case though. But might be worth checking.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to spam all the way aroudd my question with code. But yes, I already have this in my project too. The problem is that the task is registered yes, I can select it via the admin site in the select field options. But I want to add it to the db automatically.